# Catching axios request errors application wide

Tags: javascript, axios

In my SPA I am using axios to make requests to the API. I currently use axios request interceptors to add auth headers to requests but I also wanted to use them to catch 401 errors and remove the locally stored auth token.

I attempted to add this to the current interceptor

```
   axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
        // Set user headers only if they are not blank.
        // If DTA gets a lot of request quickly, it won't return headers for some requests
        // so you need a way to keep headers in localStorage to getting set to undefined
        if (response.headers['access-token']) {
            localStorage.setItem('access-token', response.headers['access-token'])
            localStorage.setItem('client', response.headers.client)
            localStorage.setItem('uid', response.headers.uid)
            localStorage.setItem('token-type', response.headers['token-type'])
        }

        if (response.status === 401) {
            localStorage.setItem('access-token', '')
            localStorage.setItem('client', '')
            localStorage.setItem('uid', '')
            localStorage.setItem('token-type', '')
        }
        // You have to return the response here or you won't have access to it
        // later
        return response
    })
```

But I found out the interceptors don't seem to run when the status returns an error code. Is there any way I can catch these errors application wide without having to add this error handling to every request manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To handle the errors from a response, you need to use the second parameter of the callback in response interceptor.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  // Set user headers only if they are not blank.
  // If DTA gets a lot of request quickly, it won't return headers for some requests
  // so you need a way to keep headers in localStorage to getting set to undefined
  if (response.headers['access-token']) {
    localStorage.setItem('access-token', response.headers['access-token']);
    localStorage.setItem('client', response.headers.client);
    localStorage.setItem('uid', response.headers.uid);
    localStorage.setItem('token-type', response.headers['token-type']);
  }

  // You have to return the response here or you won't have access to it
  // later
  return response;
}, (error) => {
  // do what you want to do when error happens
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    localStorage.setItem('access-token', '');
    localStorage.setItem('client', '');
    localStorage.setItem('uid', '');
    localStorage.setItem('token-type', '');
  }

  else if(error.response.status === 500) {
    // do something for all 500 errors
  } else {
    // do something for all other error codes
  }

  // should reject the promise so your api call goes to catch block
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Refer [official axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) for more info

I have an axios interceptor library published in npm. You can refer to the source code for more details on error handling in interceptors.

[axios-retry-intercceptor](https://github.com/flexdinesh/axios-retry-interceptor/blob/a89e391580789901919cc4bef5d77e11d9c7e0d1/src/axios-retry-interceptor.js#L23)

Comment: `error` seems to be a single string (Error: "Request failed with status code 401"). error.statusCode is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Add second function to interceptor 'errorresponseHandler':

```
function errorResponseHandler(error) {

}

// apply interceptor on response
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    errorResponseHandler
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define and export an error handler function that accepts an `error` parameter in one of your helper, util etc. classes, then you can call this method with one line inside every catch block.

Or,

You define a `doRequest()` method that handles the sending and response handling of the process altogether, and feed that method with your custom request-related parameters, like a JSON object of `{ url: 'A', method: X, data : Y}`, call this helper method from everywhere.